# Spark Kotlin - create empty Dataset

Tags: apache-spark, kotlin

I am playing around with Kotlin for Spark: https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/08/introducing-kotlin-for-apache-spark-preview/

and I am trying to create an empty Dataset based on a data class:

```
data class Company(val ticker:String)

val ds:Dataset<Company> = spark.createDataset() // <- don't know what to put in the brackets
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out by myself:

```
  val emptyList:List<Company> = emptyList()
  var ds = emptyList.toDS(spark)
```

Answer (score 0):

A way simpler way would be:

```kotlin
withSpark {
    val ds = dsOf<Company>()
}
```

or, what will be introduced in version 1.2.0:

```kotlin
withSpark {
    val ds = emptyDataset<Company>()
}
```